# best way to check is element visible protractor

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

Somebody knows the best way to check is element visible or no with the protractor?
I do something like this:

```
element.isPresent().then(result=>{
      expect(result).toBeFalsy();
});
```

It works fine. But I wolud like to check is element visible.

If I use:

```
element.isDisplayed().then(result=>{
       expect(result).toBeFalsy();
});
```

method isDisplayed return *Failed: No element found using locator*
How to check is element not visible on the page?

Answer (score 1):

isPresent returns true if the element is available in Dom. it wont check if its enabled or hidden
where as idDisplayed returns true if the element is available in Dom and it is enabled. Sometimes the element might be displayed but you may need to wait for few secs before it is enabled to perform action. you can also try

```
 let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 let waitTime = 3000;  //in ms (3 secs)
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), waitTime);
```

check here for different types of expected conditions
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

or also you can also use

```
element.isPresent().then(function() {
expect(element.isenabled()).toBeTruthy();
})
```